# psycopg2 vs MySQLdb backslash escaping behaviour

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, psycopg2, mysql-python

```
import MySQLdb
import psycopg2

# CREATE DATABASE mytest CHARACTER SET utf8;
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="anton",
        passwd="password",db="mytest")

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("drop table if exists mytable")
cur.execute("create table mytable (textcol text)")
cur.execute("insert into mytable values (' some \\\\ escaped stuff')")
cur.execute("select * from mytable")
print(cur.fetchall())


# CREATE DATABASE mytest ENCODING 'UTF8';
db=psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",user="anton",
        password="password",dbname="mytest")

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("drop table if exists mytable")
cur.execute("create table mytable (textcol text)")
cur.execute("insert into mytable values (' some \\\\ escaped stuff')")
cur.execute("select * from mytable")

print(cur.fetchall())
```

Which outputs:

```
((' some \\ escaped stuff',),)
[(' some \\\\ escaped stuff',)]
```

Basically, all I want is to be able to use the same insert sql (which I can't modify) and be able to get the same thing back for the `text` column using both db drivers by adding some parameter to the connection. I couldn't find how to control this behaviour on either, so am stuck.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you run your query now?

Comment: There is no error, I just need consistent behaviour from both drivers so I can have one code path to deal with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both are possible.

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="anton",
        passwd="password",db="mytest", sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES")
```

Will tell `mysql` [to treat backslashes like the standard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes), and so  [like `postgresql` has been by default since 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-compatible.html). Setting the `sql_mode` like this is probably not what you want though, so something like `sql_mode="TRADITIONAL,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES"` (note there is no space between them, you get an error with a space) will give you a strict `sql_mode` with the SQL standard behaviour for escaping.

Going the other way is also possible - you can get `postgresql` to act in a similar way to `mysql` in the default config (on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
db=psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",user="anton",
        password="password",dbname="mytest", options='-c standard_conforming_strings=off')
```

Which essentially [puts `postgresql` back in pre-9.1 mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-compatible.html) concerning backslash escaping.